# How to correctly negate a predicate bounded by some quantifiers?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, propositional-logic, predicate-logic

this is a problem which was asked in GATE CS 2010.

**This is question statement:

Q:** Suppose the predicate F(x, y, t) is used to represent the statement that person x can fool person y at time t. which one of the statements below expresses best the meaning of the formula ∀x∃y∃t(¬F(x, y, t))?

**Options:**

**A:** Everyone can fool some person at some time.
**B:** No one can fool everyone all the time.
**C:** Everyone cannot fool some person all the time.
**D:** No one can fool some person at some time.

**According to my solution:**
If F(x): person x can fool person y at time t.
Then
$\forall$x $\exists$y $\exists$t ( ¬F( x, y, t ) ) 
is same as "Not all person x can fool some person y at some time t.
which can be rewritten as "No one can fool some person at some time".
Hence Option D must be the correct one.

However I am wrong.

How to approach these type of problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how general *this type of problem* is so I can't tell you if this will always be the best approach, but in this case you can move the negation to the top for more clarity.

$$\forall x\ \exists y\ \exists t\ [\neg F(x,y,t)]\equiv \forall x\ \exists y\ [\neg\ \forall t F(x,y,t)]\equiv \forall x\ [\neg\ \forall y\ \forall t F(x,y,t)]\equiv \neg [\exists x\ \forall y\ \forall t F(x,y,t)]$$

From this you should be able to find the correct answer, which is:

> B

Comment: Very nice approach. I understood what you did. But can we also move from the left to the right?

Comment: Yes, so long as you correctly invert the operators encountered (e.g. $\neg\ \exists x$ becomes $\forall x\ \neg$), and distribute when appropriate (e.g. $\neg (A \lor B)$ is $(\neg A) \land (\neg B)$)

Answer (score 1):

F(x,y,t)⟹  person x can fool person y at time t.

For the sake of simplicity propagate negation sign outward by applying De Morgan's law.

∀x∃y∃t(¬F(x,y,t))≡¬∃x∀y∀t(F(x,y,t)) [By applying De Morgan's law.]

Now converting ¬∃x∀y∀t(F(x,y,t)) to English is simple.

¬∃x∀y∀t(F(x,y,t))⟹ There does not exist a person who can fool everyone all the time.
Which means No one can fool everyone all the time.

So, option (B) is correct.